# MySQL query with LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `stories`, `story_types`, and `comments`

The following query retrieves all of the records in the `stories` table, gets their `story_types`, and the number of comments associated with each story:

```
         SELECT s.id AS id,
                s.story_date AS datetime,
                s.story_content AS content,
                t.story_type_label AS type_label,
                t.story_type_slug AS type_slug,
                COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count
           FROM stories AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN story_types AS t ON s.story_type_id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments AS c ON s.id = c.story_id 
       GROUP BY s.id;
```

Now what I want to do is only retrieve a record from `stories WHERE s.id = 1` (that's the primary key). I have tried the following, but it still returns all of the records:

```
         SELECT s.id AS id,
                s.story_date AS datetime,
                s.story_content AS content,
                t.story_type_label AS type_label,
                t.story_type_slug AS type_slug,
                COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count
           FROM stories AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN story_types AS t ON s.story_type_id = t.id
                AND s.id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments AS c ON s.id = c.story_id 
       GROUP BY s.id;
```

I have also tried a `WHERE` clause at the end, which throws an error.

Can someone point out the correct syntax for a condition like this in this situation?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.47. Thanks.

Comment: You *did* put the WHERE clause before the GROUP BY, did you?

Comment: Aren't you missing a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: From your title, there is no LEFT INNER JOIN; LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same thing.

Comment: @OMG: The GROUP BY in the upper code sample is mis-aligned. I can hardly read the query. :-P (@Noah: I second that request: If the people here are to invest time in you, you should invest some time in them as well.)

Comment: @Tomalak: If you won't adjust your bifocals, I'll revert it back to the original :P

Comment: @OMG, Tomalak: Will do. Thank you. And I fixed the title.

Comment: @Noah: Meh. Now the GROUP BY is not misaligned anymore. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you put the WHERE after the GROUP BY, which is illegal. See this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) on the SELECT syntax in MySQL.
Try this:

```
SELECT
    s.id AS id,
    s.story_date AS datetime,
    s.story_content AS content,
    t.story_type_label AS type_label,
    t.story_type_slug AS type_slug,
    COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count
FROM
    stories AS s
    LEFT JOIN story_types AS t ON s.story_type_id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON s.id = c.story_id 
WHERE
    s.id = 1
GROUP BY
    s.id;
```

*editor's note: I reformatted the code to highlight the query structure*

Comment: It is not intuitive to me that this WHERE would go in the second JOIN (or is it in the second join?), but this seems to do what I intended. Thank you so much.

Comment: No, it's a separate clause from the OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @Noah - the different sections of a query are functionally distinct.  SELECT, FROM, WHERE and GROUP are the different sections in this query.  The WHERE clause is applied to the query as a whole, not to a particular JOIN within the FROM clause.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Yes, I had the misconception that the GROUP BY in this case somehow belonged to the second JOIN. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Following up this comment on the accepted answer:

> It is not intuitive to me that this WHERE would go in the second JOIN

This is just to outline how proper code formatting enhances understanding. Here is how I usually format SQL:

```
SELECT 
  s.id               AS id,
  s.story_date       AS datetime,
  s.story_content    AS content,
  t.story_type_label AS type_label,
  t.story_type_slug  AS type_slug,
  COUNT(c.id)        AS comment_count
FROM 
  stories                  AS s
  LEFT JOIN story_types    AS t ON t.id = s.story_type_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments AS c ON s.id = c.story_id 
WHERE
  s.id = 1
GROUP BY
  s.id;
```

The WHERE is not on the second join. There is only one WHERE clause allowed in a SELECT statement, and it always is top level.

PS: Also note that in many database engines (apart from MySQL) it is illegal to use a GROUP BY clause and then selecting columns without aggregating them via functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `COUNT()`. IMHO this is bad style and a bad habit to get into.